# Python - generators, iterators, and speed

Tags: python-2.7, generator

[Edited to reflect the comments so far, and my further reading.]

Question: I'm confused why the following three versions of the eta function,all written in python, are all about the same speed, namely linear in "bound", and with similar constants.

As a bit of background: I needed a reasonably fast version of the eta function for a computation.  The definition of the eta function can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).  Before giving the three functions, we need a simple helper function.

```
def chi(n): # Dirichlet character                                                     
    n = n%12
    if n == 1 or n == 11:
        return 1
    if n == 5 or n == 7:
        return -1
    return 0
```

Now the three versions that are puzzling me.  First we have the obvious one-liner, direct from a definition of eta in terms of Jacobi theta functions.

```
def eta_Dedekind_theta(tau, bound = 50):
    assert tau.imag > 0
    r = Exp(Pi*I*tau/12)
    # sum_1^infty chi(n) r^(n^2)                                                      
    return sum([chi(n)*r**(n**2) for n in range(1,bound+1)])
```

Second we have the obvious modification of the one-liner: replace the list comprehension with a generator expression.

```
def eta_Dedekind_theta_round(tau, bound = 50):
    assert tau.imag > 0
    r = Exp(Pi*I*tau/12)
    # sum_1^infty chi(n) r^(n^2)                                                      
    return sum((chi(n)*r**(n**2) for n in range(1,bound+1)))
```

But this version is ever so slightly *slower* - why does replacing the list comprehension with a generator slow things down?  Finally, here is the version I coded first. I thought this was very clever, as it avoids exponentiation with quadratically large exponent.

```
def eta_Dedekind_theta_clever(tau, bound = 50):
    assert tau.imag > 0
    r = Exp(Pi*I*tau/12)
    r2 = r**2
    lin = 1
    quad = r
    sum = 0
    # sum_1^infty chi(n) r^(n^2)                                                      
    for n in range(1, bound+1):
        sum = sum + chi(n)*quad # n^2                                                 
        lin = lin*r2 # 2n                                                             
        quad = quad*lin*r # n^2 + 2n + 1 = (n+1)^2                                    
    return sum
```

Indeed, this version is ever so slightly faster than both of the previous.  But I thought that this would be linear while the one-liners would be very slow due to the cost of exponentiation.  But that is not the case: timings show that *all* of them are linear in "bound" with roughly similar constants.  I guess I don't understand the cost of operations in python.

Comment: Please include your timing code...

Comment: Inside of ipython, I set tau = 1j and then ran 1000 iterations of each function, with bound increasing from 100 to 700 in steps of 100.

Comment: Here is the timing function --- def repeat(func, arg, bound, times): for i in range(times): a = func(arg, bound=bound)

Comment: You're not "making the generator a tuple" -- a generator in parens () is actually a generator expression, whereas a the brackets [] give a list comprehension. The generator is more memory friendly according to the docs but perhaps therefore slower?

Comment: Ok, I went off and read PEP 202 and 289 - I guess that the sizes I tested weren't sufficiently large for the "niceness" of the generator expression to kick in.  I also spent some time with the function c_pow in the file complexobject.c in the python source.  So python handles complex exponentiation in a fairly non-stupid way.  _In_particular_ it appears that all three of the functions above are linear in the number of operations on floats.  So...

Comment: My question is really -- is there a good pocket reference for the various basic operations in python, and how should I think of their costs in terms of space and time?  I want to write code in python because it is so much easier than C.  But I also want to know what the darn thing is doing (so my code is correct and fast (enough)).

Comment: @Sam Nead: this should be a good read: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips